# php form multiple image upload

Tags: php, upload

I am trying to create a form with two inputs in it. 
one is the (folder name)
the second one is a browse button that lets you pick multiple files and upload them at the same time.
is there any php code that I can use ? or any php tutorial ?

example of what I want: 
create new folder in the dictionary with (folder name) and upload pictures inside the (folder name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the for each loop.
this might help:
http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php
there are some good examples under the page